# TimerTask extended class fails on rescheduling of Task using java.util.Timer

Tags: java, android, exception, timer, timertask

```
class Rhythm extends TimerTask
{
  private java.util.Timer SegmentTimer; 
  pubic void start()
  {
    this.Segmenttimer = new Timer(true);
    Segmenttimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 0, 1000);
  }
  public void run() {}
  public void stop()
  {
    this.SegmentTimer.Cancel();
  }
}

class Program
{
  Rhythm rhythm = new Rhythm();

  for (item : List)
  {
    rhythm.start();
  }
}
```

This is my sample program.  I have some logics to load the rhythm object. In this case I just showed only creating a new instance before the for each loop starts. The reason is I am initializing a list of rhythm object based on a json data. So, I would like to optimize the process and avoid the repeated IO operation for parsing the json data inside the loop.

My problem is the second iteration of the loop fails and says TimeTask is scheduled already.

Kindly help resolving this.

Comment: your code is incomplete... where is the run method in the TimerTask???

Comment: Hi I have it in my code. But I missed in this thread. That is different part.

But pls tell me how to resolve that timer task schedule issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is incomplete... a child class of TimerTask must implement the run method, you need to add that, on the other hand, you can not restart a Timer twice, so this part is not correct:

```
for (item : List) {
    rhythm.start();
  }
```

maybe you need to define item object so they have their own Timer that you can start in the loop

if the notes are not related with the rythm then you can do:

```
for (item : List) {
    rhythm = new Rhythm();
    rhythm.start(); 
}
```

Comment: I just added that foreach loop as a sample. Also I have a run method. When mentioning in this code I didn't included that. That's it.

Can you please bit clear how to fix that timertask issue?

Comment: we need more info about the objects in the list.... what are those? Do  you mean maybe to start a ryrhm on everyone of those elements in the list..

Comment: yes exactly. The list object is not related to rhythm content.  For example to say,  For each music note the rhythm will start.